# npm jshint installation and working by Grunt & nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, jshint

I got node.js installed on Windows with npm package. 
I have a project in D drive as D:>projectD 
I am trying to run jshint along with SASS,concat,etc. All are working fine, but getting error on jshint as:

```
Local npm module "jshint" not found.Is it installed?
Warning: Task 'jshint' not found. Use --force to continue.
```

For installation of jshint used the following commands:

```
npm install -g jshint
D:>projectD>npm install --save-dev jshint
```

Gruntfile.js

```
jshint:{
 all: ['<%= meta.srcPath %>engine/js/myjs1.js']
},

//plugin declaration
grunt.loadNpmTasks('jshint');

// Default task
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat','sass','jshint']);
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test-Project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "jshint": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

Can someone help me out why I am not able to work with jshint along with other tasks in grunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your Gruntfile is wrong.
You want to configurate Grunt. Therefore you need to init the configuration by using `grunt.initConfig`

So in your case

```
grunt.initConfig({
  jshint: {
    all: ['<%= meta.srcPath %>engine/js/myjs1.js']
  }
});
```

And I believe that the module is the `grunt-contrib-jshint` module which you need.
So your loadNpmTask would be `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');`
And your `registerTask` only needs to contain `jshint` since you do only load and configurate `jshint`.

You are missing the `module.exports = function(grunt) { }`. You need to export your configuration as a function.

All in all your configuration should look like the following

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
        all: ['<%= meta.srcPath %>engine/js/myjs1.js']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);

};
```